# Migrating from jQuery 1 to jQuery 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

I bought an HTML template only to find it uses jQuery 1. I am trying to upgrade to jQuery 3 but I have an issue with this piece of code in the template's main.js file:

```
var background_image = function() {
    $("[data-bg-img]").each(function() {
        var attr = $(this).attr('data-bg-img');
        if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false && attr !== "") {
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url('+attr+')');
        }
    });  
};
```

The HTML part this references is:

```
 <figure class="deal-thumbnail embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" data-bg-img="'.$dealimage.'">
```

This stopped working when upgrading to jQuery 3.4.1. Not sure what to do.

CSS:

```
*[data-bg-img] {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
 }
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Check the console for errors

Comment: Is that the final rendered HTML? Looks like it's meant to be getting a string passed in by a PHP script.

Comment: here's a list of deprecated functions in jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/ looks like your code is still compatible

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There are no errors in console.

Comment: @Gavin I am passing a variable with PHP. The resulting HTML is as expected which is just an image src.

Comment: The code you've shown works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3djq1sep/1/. The issue must lie elsewhere. As such we can't help you, given the information you've provided so far.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for taking the time to create a fiddle. I'll go through the rest of the code and see where the issue could be. Thanks again.

Comment: Please see edit for CSS. not sure if this is related.

Comment: Still works I'm afraid: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3djq1sep/2/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah well, guess I have to dig deep and figure this out. I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I overlooked the most basic document.ready function, which meant the script didn't even run. In jQuery 1.x.x it was written as:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {

})
```

I changed it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

})
```

Comment: it's great you solved, next time please remember to include console errors in your question, you'll get quicker answers.